# CBService discover cache

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-bluetooth

Trying to discover a BLE services. I had an upgrade of the firmware for the hardware adding a new service, but i can't discover it using my app. The light blue app can discover it without problems. It looks like the CBCentralManager is caching the discovered peripherals with services. Any idea on how to reset it?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried restarting your iOS device?

Comment: an iOS user should restart the device if i upgrade the firmware??? I mean if i release a new version of the app, and a new firmware for the BLE, i should tell to the user "restart your device"... sounds bad.